# QMainWindow vs QWidget

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qmainwindow

I can't find good explanations about the different usage of QMainWindow vs. QWidget in PyQt5 (and Qt in general, I guess). From what I've read, QMainWindow inherits from QWidget, so should be able to do everything QWidget can and more. But when I try to convert an example I've found from QWidget into QMainWindow, the layout gets screwed up.

The example I'm trying to work off is from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyqt/pyqt_qstackedwidget.htm. (My GUI will have a StackedWidget as central widget, with a sidepanel for navigation, so getting this example to work in a QMainWidget would be a great basis for my own code.)

PyQT5-converted and slightly shortened version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QFormLayout, QLabel, QRadioButton, QCheckBox,
                             QListWidget, QStackedWidget, QLineEdit,
                             QHBoxLayout, QGridLayout
                             )
from PyQt5.Qt import QWidget, QMainWindow

class StackedExample(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(stackedExample, self).__init__()
        self.leftlist = QListWidget ()
        self.leftlist.insertItem (0, 'Contact' )
        self.leftlist.insertItem (1, 'Personal' )

        self.stack1 = QWidget()
        self.stack2 = QWidget()

        self.stack1UI()
        self.stack2UI()

        self.Stack = QStackedWidget (self)
        self.Stack.addWidget (self.stack1)
        self.Stack.addWidget (self.stack2)
        grid = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(grid)
        grid.addWidget(self.leftlist,0,0)
        grid.addWidget(self.Stack,0,1)

        self.leftlist.currentRowChanged.connect(self.display)
        self.resize(300,100)
        self.show()

    def stack1UI(self):
        layout = QFormLayout()
        layout.addRow("Name",QLineEdit())
        layout.addRow("Address",QLineEdit())
        self.stack1.setLayout(layout)

    def stack2UI(self):
        layout = QFormLayout()
        sex = QHBoxLayout()
        sex.addWidget(QRadioButton("Male"))
        sex.addWidget(QRadioButton("Female"))
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Sex"),sex)
        layout.addRow("Date of Birth",QLineEdit())

        self.stack2.setLayout(layout)

    def display(self,i):
        self.Stack.setCurrentIndex(i)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = StackedExample()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This code worked fine while it was based on QWidget, but when it's based on QMainWidget (like in the above version), everything gets crammed into the upper left corner.

**What changes are neccessary to show a layout that works for QWidget in a QMainWindow?**

Comment: In a QMainWindow you should set the central widget with `setCentralWidget` (or something similar)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A QMainWindow must have a central widget to display correctly.  You need to define a central widget and then add any layouts to it instead of the main window.

```
class StackedExample(QMainWindow):

def __init__(self):
    QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    self.leftlist = QListWidget()
    self.leftlist.insertItem(0, 'Contact' )
    self.leftlist.insertItem(1, 'Personal' )

    self.central_widget = QWidget()               # define central widget
    self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)    # set QMainWindow.centralWidget

    self.stack1 = QWidget()
    self.stack2 = QWidget()

    self.stack1UI()
    self.stack2UI()

    self.Stack = QStackedWidget (self)
    self.Stack.addWidget (self.stack1)
    self.Stack.addWidget (self.stack2)
    grid = QGridLayout()
    self.centralWidget().setLayout(grid)          # add the layout to the central widget
    grid.addWidget(self.leftlist,0,0)
    grid.addWidget(self.Stack,0,1)

    self.leftlist.currentRowChanged.connect(self.display)
    self.resize(300,100)
    self.show()
```

There are also other areas besides centralWidget defined for a QMainWindow.  [Here is the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html) for QMainWindow.  It explains this in more detail.